# NullPointerException while running HornetQ example

Tags: java, jms, hornetq

I'm new to JMS and am trying to embed HornetQ with JMS and Spring into my project. Here I download and run [this example](https://github.com/hornetq/hornetq/tree/2.4.x/examples/jms/embedded-simple). However, line:

```
ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory) jmsServer.lookup("/cf");
```

will always set `cf` as null, and I can't find "cf" in any configuration files. What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is wrong indeed.

Looking at the `hornetq-jms.xml` file, it should be

`jmsServer.lookup("ConnectionFactory")`

instead of  `jmsServer.lookup("/cf")`

Or change the

`<entry name="ConnectionFactory"/>`

to `<entry name="/cf"/>`

in that `hornetq-jms.xml` file.